# Can someone prove that the inverse of $x^x$ is not an elementary function?

Tags: inverse, elementary-functions, inverse-function

I want to prove that the inverse of $f(x)=x^x$ is not an elementary function.

With elementary function I mean a function of one variable which is the composition of a finite number of arithmetic operations $+$, $–$, $\times$,$\div$, exponentials, logarithms, constants, and solutions of algebraic equations (a generalization of $n$'th roots).

I have no idea on how to do it, I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you call an "elementary function"?

Comment: @paf. A function of one variable which is the composition of a finite number of arithmetic operations (+ – × ÷), exponentials, logarithms, constants, and solutions of algebraic equations (a generalization of nth roots).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) provides a link to this paper: $$$$ Chow, Timothy Y. (1999), "What is a closed-form number?", American Mathematical Monthly, 106 (5): 440–448, doi:10.2307/2589148, MR 1699262.

Answer (score 5):

Equivalently, you want to prove that the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W$ is not elementary:
$f^{-1}(y) = \ln(y)/W(\ln(y))$.  This was asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135911/how-to-prove-lamberts-w-function-is-not-elementary).

Answer (score 0):

We must be careful: A function has an inverse iff it is injective and surjective (bijective). You didn't specify the domain of your function $f$. Therefore we can assume the maximal real domain or the maximal complex domain. $f$ is not injective with these domains and doesn't have an inverse (inverse function) therefore.

If a function $f$ with $f(x)=x^x$ is bijective or not, depends on its domain and codomain. Each function can be decomposed into bijective subfunctions by decomposing its domain and/or codomain.
Our proof holds for all bijective subfunctions of $f$ with open domain and therefore for all [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) of $f$ with open domain.
$\ $

$$f(x)=x^x$$

From the definition of the inverse $f^{-1}$ of $f$, we get
$$f(f^{-1}(x))=x.$$
$y=f^{-1}(x)$:
$$f(y)=x$$
$$y^y=x$$

In the first part, we solve the equation.
In the second part, we show that the solution is not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
In the last step, we have to show that the branches of Lambert W are not elementary functions.

**1.)** In the first step, we will solve the equation.

$$y^y=x$$
$$e^{\ln(y)\ y}=x$$
$$\text{Ln}(e^{\ln(y)\ y})=\text{Ln}(x)$$
$\text{Ln(z)}=\ln(z)+2k_1\pi i\ \ (k_1\in\mathbb{Z})$:
$$\ln(y)\ y=\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i\ \ \ \ \ \ (k_1\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$e^t=y$:
$$\ln(e^t)\ e^t=\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i$$
$$(t+2k_2\pi i)e^t=\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i\ \ \ \ \ \ (k_2\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$$(t+2k_2\pi i)e^{t+2k_2\pi i}=e^{2k_2\pi i}(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)$$
$e^{2k_2\pi i}=1$:
$$(t+2k_2\pi i)e^{t+2k_2\pi i}=\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i$$
Applying [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$t+2k_2\pi i=W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)\ \ \ \ \ \ (n\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$$t=W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)-2k_2\pi i$$
$t=\text{Ln}(y)$:
$$\text{Ln}(y)=W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)-2k_2\pi i$$
$\text{Ln(y)}=\ln(y)+2k_3\pi i\ \ (k_3\in\mathbb{Z})$:
$$\ln(y)+2k_3\pi i=W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)-2k_2\pi i$$
$$\ln(y)=W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)+2k_4\pi i\ \ \ \ \ \ (k_4\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$$y=e^{W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)+2k_4\pi i}$$
$$y=e^{W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)}e^{2k_4\pi i}$$
$e^{2k_4\pi i}=1$:
$$y=e^{W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)}$$

**2.)** In the second step, we will show that the solution is not an elementary function.

Assume our inverse $f^{-1}$ is an elementary function $E\ $ (1):
$$y=E(x)$$
$$e^{W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)}=E(x)$$
$$\text{Ln}(e^{W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)})=\text{Ln}(E(x))$$
$$W_n(\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i)=\ln(E(x))+2k_2\pi i\ \ \ \ (k_2\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$\ln(x)+2k_1\pi i\to t,x\to e^{-2k_1\pi i+t}$:
$$W_n(t)=\ln(E(e^{-2k_1\pi i+t}))+2k_2\pi i$$
The right-hand side of this equation is the function term of an elementary function (a composition of elementary functions), the left-hand side is the function term of the branches of Lambert W. If our assumption (1) is true, the branches of Lambert W are elementary functions.

**3.)** In the last step, we have to show that the branches of Lambert W are not elementary functions.

see e.g:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135911/how-to-prove-lamberts-w-function-is-not-elementary
[Why is it that the Lambert W relation cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362625/why-is-it-that-the-lambert-w-relation-cannot-be-expressed-in-terms-of-elementary)
[How can we show that A(z,e^z) and A(ln(z),z) have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-no-function-f-with-fz-az-ez-have-elementary-inverses)